# MySQL 5.7 JSON: how to set variable to json_contains_path like '$.name'

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

I use MySQL5.7 and store json in mysql, now i need to do some analysis on this json.

Such as below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `json_test1` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

insert test data:

```
insert into json_test1 (name, json)
values ('lily', '{"age": 22, "lily": "ldfd"}'),
       ('sam','{"sam":"dfsf"}'),
       ('k','{"arm":"aaa"}'),
       ('cd','{"xl":"bbb"}');
```

[image: list]

Now, i need to check if `json` key contains `name`, for example: `('sam','{"sam":"sam"}')`, if `json` contains key 'sam', so for this single one, i can use below sql:

```
select json_contains_path(json, 'one','$.sam') jsonC
from json_test1 where name='sam';
```

[image]

Output is 1, so `json` contains key 'sam', but **how can i check all these data to see if key exist in `json`**, in this condition, i need pass a variable to function `json_contains_path(json, 'one','$.{name}')` , but i don't know how to set variable in this function.

**Expected result**:

[image]

Anyone know that?

Comment: @Akina updated my question.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `CONCAT()` function such as

```
SELECT name, JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(json, 'one',CONCAT('$."',name,'"')) AS jsonExists
  FROM json_test1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cdd9433e6c289d1e78cc84ff299dd28b)</kbd>